# A problem with jsp requested parameters in tomcat

Tags: jsp, unicode, tomcat7

I've created a JSP project with netbeans 7.0 and tomcat 7.0 too with no problem.

When I export it to a WAR and deploy it into my Tomcat server this line doesn't work:

```
<% if (request.getParameter("submit").contains("اضافه")) { ...
```

but these ones works:

```
<% if (request.getParameter("emplist") != null) { ...
```

How is this problem caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What do you mea by "doesn't work". The JSP doesn't compile? If so, what's the error message? It compiles but doesn't do what you think it should? What happens exactly, and how do you run it?

Comment: it doesn't return me any error!!
it seems no requested parameter or an if statement exists!

Comment: Before the if test, include some logging statements: System.out.println("parameter = [" + request.getParameter("submit") + "]");System.out.println("parameter = [" + "اضافه" + "]"); and see it you really have this parameter and if it really contains this string. You could display all the numeric values of the chars to really make sure.

Comment: when deploy it by netbeans everything is ok!
but when deploy the web archive that created by netbeans IDE in dist directory or even by Eclipse (after importing to it) i found this problem!

Comment: i do that test too!!

<%if (request.getParameter("emplist") != null) { out.print("Ok!?")...%>
print Ok on page
but :
<%if (request.getParameter("submit").contains("اضافه")) {out.print("OK!")... %>
nothing printed!!

i change the persian (unicode) word ("اضافه") to  "add" but nothings happened!

Comment: But what's the value of request.getParameter("submit")?

Comment: I'm not sure about how Arabics communicate with each other in written language, but in English, statement sentences normally end with a period `.`, not with an exclamation mark `!`. If you continuously use exclamation marks, you overcome like angry and you're putting pressure on others. Please pay some extra attention to this.

Comment: the value of request.getParameter("submit") is: "حذف یا اضافه"
dear @BalusC when I deploy it with netbeans into Tomcat (that registered into netbeans) EVERYTHING was good and ok
even now when deploy with netbeans
but I'm going to publish it into internet and for this publishing i need a war file that appears these problems!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml`, you can add a filter to enable character encoding to UTF-8

Add the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>setCharacterFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ignore</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you want to URL to be encoded to include UTF-8, you will have to add a `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to your Tomcat Connector.

Find your HTTP connector (in `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`, usually you can find a port `8080` assigned) and add the attribute `URIEncoding` as above, as follows:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    />
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is your deployment tomcat version same as your development one ?

This might be related to request encoding problem . you should set encoding to UTF-8 either by calling the setCharacterEncoding of HttpServletRequest object or by setting utf8 charset in your form .

Comment: you right!
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
import = "com.vaannila.*,java.util.*"
%>

is enough!? or not!

Comment: no , it's not enough . you should set it in the form you want to post.

Answer (score 0):

Like following. You also can create the custom filter class to set the encoding of the request to UTF-8

```
public class UnicodeFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
   }
   public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
     //Get init parameter
   }
   public void destroy() {
     //add code to release any resource
   }
}
```